# Preserve user zoom state when updating JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using `JFreeChart 1.0.14` to plot a `XYSeries`. I do have access to all the elements (`ChartPanel`, `JFreeChart`, `XYSeriesCollection`, `XYSeries`). From time to time there is new data to plot, so I update my series (for simplicity let's assume there is just one series):

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        XYSeries xyData = new XYSeries("Trace");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            xyData.add(data[0][i], data[1][i], false);

        collection.removeAllSeries();
        collection.addSeries(xyData);

        chart.getXYPlot().setRangeAxis(createNewAxis());
    }
});
```

This works all great. But I have one problem. The user can zoom by dragging in the plot. This zoom gets reset every time, the data is updated. Which makes sense, because I create new axes. How can I preserve the user zoom state? As the user can also choose autorange/range, I don't want to do some sort of hack with those (`Axis#setRange/setAutoRange`). I found something about `ChartPanel#getScaleX()`. But this is always `1.0` at the start of the above mentioned `invokeLater`. Also I can not find any `ChartPanel.setScaleX`.

Am I doing something wrong or is there another way of preserving the user zoom state without changing the range/autorange behaviour of the axis?

BTW: I **have** to recreate the axes, because they can also switch between logscale and linscale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not figure out how to take over the "user zoom state" from one axis to another. Therefore I made sure not to refresh the axis if it is not needed (=no change of scale between logarithmic/linear). If there is a change, the user zoom state will be lost, which is unfortunate. But that doesn't happen that often and is user controlled, so the user might be ok with the zoom state reset.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you need to create a new `XYSeries xyData` each time you add a new point or call `removeAllSeries()`

This example shows how to add dynamic data to an `XYSeriesCollection`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.LogAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.time.Millisecond;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

/**
 * A demonstration application showing a XYseries chart where you can
 * dynamically add (random) data by clicking on a button.
 */
public class DynamicDataDemo1 extends ApplicationFrame {
    /**
     * Constructs a new demonstration application.
     * 
     * @param title
     *            the frame title.
     */
    public DynamicDataDemo1(String title) {
        super(title);
        MyDemoPanel demoPanel = new MyDemoPanel();
        setContentPane(demoPanel);
    }



    static class MyDemoPanel extends DemoPanel implements ActionListener {
        /** The time series data. */

        /** The most recent value added. */
        private double lastValue1 = 200.0;
        private double lastValue2 = 200.0;
        private XYPlot plot;
        private boolean logAxis = false;
        private String lastSeries = "";
        private final XYSeriesCollection dataset;
        private static String SERIES_NAME =  "Random Data ";
        private static int seriesNumber =  0;
        /**
         * Creates a new instance.
         */
        public MyDemoPanel() {
            super(new BorderLayout());
            lastSeries = SERIES_NAME + (seriesNumber++);
            XYSeries series = new XYSeries(lastSeries);
            dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
            ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(createChart(dataset));
            chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
            addChart(chartPanel.getChart());
            JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
            buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
            JButton button = new JButton("Add New Data Item");
            button.setActionCommand("ADD_DATA");
            button.addActionListener(this);
            buttonPanel.add(button);
            {
                JButton button2 = new JButton("Switch Axis");
                button2.setActionCommand("SWITCH_AXIS");
                button2.addActionListener(this);
                buttonPanel.add(button2);
            }
            {
                JButton button2 = new JButton("Add Series");
                button2.setActionCommand("ADD_SERIES");
                button2.addActionListener(this);
                buttonPanel.add(button2);
            }
            add(chartPanel);
            add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        private JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {
            JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Dynamic Data Demo", "Time", "Value", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
            plot = (XYPlot) result.getPlot();
            ValueAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
            domainAxis.setAutoRange(true);
            final ValueAxis rangeAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
            rangeAxis.setAutoRange(true);
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("ADD_DATA")) {
                double factor1 = 0.90 + 0.2 * Math.random();
                double factor2 = 0.90 + 0.2 * Math.random();
                this.lastValue1 = this.lastValue1 * factor1;
                this.lastValue2 = this.lastValue2 * factor2;
                Millisecond now = new Millisecond();
                System.out.println("Now = " + now.toString());
                XYSeries series = dataset.getSeries(lastSeries);
                series.add(this.lastValue2, this.lastValue1);
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("SWITCH_AXIS")) {
                if (!logAxis) {
                    LogAxis xAxis = new LogAxis("X");
                    LogAxis yAxis = new LogAxis("Y");               
                    updateZoom(xAxis,yAxis);
                logAxis = true;
                } else {
                    NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis("X");
                    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("Y");
                    updateZoom(xAxis,yAxis);
                    logAxis = false;
                }
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("ADD_SERIES")) {
                lastSeries = SERIES_NAME + (seriesNumber++);
                XYSeries series = new XYSeries(lastSeries);
                dataset.addSeries(series);
            }
        }

        private void (ValueAxis xAxis, ValueAxis yAxis) {
            double domainMin = plot.getDomainAxis().getRange().getLowerBound();
            double domainMax = plot.getDomainAxis().getRange().getUpperBound();
            System.out.println(domainMin + "," + domainMax);

            double rangeMin = plot.getRangeAxis().getRange().getLowerBound();
            double rangeMax = plot.getRangeAxis().getRange().getUpperBound();
            System.out.println(rangeMin + "," + rangeMax);                  

            xAxis.setRange(domainMin, domainMax);
            plot.setDomainAxis(xAxis);
            yAxis.setRange(rangeMin, rangeMax);
            plot.setRangeAxis(yAxis);

        }
    }

    public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
        return new DynamicDataDemo1.MyDemoPanel();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DynamicDataDemo1 demo = new DynamicDataDemo1("JFreeChart: Dynamic XYSeries");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This example is based on JFreeChart: DynamicDataDemo1.java.  Each time you click "Add New Data Item" a new point will be added.  In this example the Zoom will be preserved when you add a data point but not when you chage axis.

To maintain the zoom when changing the axis from normal to log scale and visa versa use the current upper and lower bound from both axis and set the `Range` of the new axis as shown in `updateZoom`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help me, because the reason, zoom is preserved in your example, is because the axis is not renewed. I can not do that (as mentioned in my question). I think, this has nothing to do with me creating a new series.

Comment: Also, my application can have an indefinite amount of series in it's collection (and they are added/removed during runtime), so I can not just work with a fix set of series and never add/remove them from the collection.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution though. :)

Comment: @brimborium Could you use `collection.getSeries("")`  in `Runnable` to get the series to update? that way you would not have to make the series into a property.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't just add some points to my series, there are completely new series to show, sometimes they replace the already displaying series (in which case I don't have to delete the old one), sometimes, they are added (while the displaying series remain).

Comment: @brimborium I think that my updated example shows how to add a series and then  add data to it.

Comment: Yes, thats clear. But that doesn't solve the problem. I want to know, how I can apply the zoom state of my old axis (which might be a NumberAxis) to my new axis (which might be a LogAxis)... Because that is reset (of course), once I set my new axis with `setRangeAxis(newAxis)`.

Comment: I just retried your example. Unfortunately, it doesn't preserve zoom state. Try this. Create a dataset. Manually zoom in to some parts. Click on "switch axes" twice. The zoom state is not preserved. It preserves the state on "add data item" and "add series", which is fine.

Comment: have you considered getting the `Axis` Upper and Lower bounds calculating the log value and then setting the Range of the new Axis?

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want, because those are set to what the user has configured. So if he zooms back out, those should be restored. (As they are when the axes are not refreshed)

Comment: @brimborium I've updated the example to show how to preserve the zoom settings when switching axis.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. That is probably what I have to do. But it's not at all what I want. The user has set some range manually with two sliders. Let's say he chose 0.1-100. That works. Now he zooms in by dragging. That work's too. Now he zooms out again (drag towards upper left corner). The range is again 0.1-100. Perfect. But when he is zoomed in and the axes are refreshed, the range will be 0.1-100 again. That's fine, but the user zoom state (within that 0.1-100 range) will be reset. So the whole 0.1-100 will be shown instead of what the user dragged...